# Is Applying Transforms Necessary?

Tags: transforms

Is it necessary to apply all transforms? Everything in my character breaks the second I apply transforms... My shader for my character's eyes, the hair, even the rotation of the eyelids ceases to function properly. I am making a character for a game, but what does applying transforms do? The scale is like 0.1, I had thought I applied it before  making the hair, but turns out I didn't , so I applied it and the hair grew out all over the place. I don't even understand why my eyelids fail to rotate properly after applying rotation.

Can anyone tell me how to apply transforms without having everything break, or is this to be expected? And what does applying transforms do?

Comment: That helps, but I still wonder about all these issues that are caused from applying scale,

Comment: The issue is that you have gone too far in your project before applying the transformations. Now you likely have parts of your project that are depending on transform data that was not zeroed out when setting up your connections, causing things to break when you apply them. Start with applied transforms before adding modifiers or constraints.

Comment: Actually, I found a great solution that wasn't on that previous post, apply transform to deltas instead of applying all transforms, posting this for anyone who finds this thread.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer in the linked post so that other users with the same problem can learn from your experience.

Comment: Well, I tried, and they deleted my post saying to not use the answer section for feedback... ? The mods are weird here.